# How to batch process a folder structure containing PNG files and output them to a similar folder structure at another directory using pngquant

Tags: windows, shell, batch-processing, image-compression, pngquant

I'm trying to process a folder directory with pngquant that has a structure of :

`C:\                                                                                                                     ├───FOLDER                                                                                                                 │   ├───0                                                                                                               │   │   └───0                                                                                                           │   ├───1                                                                                                               │   │   └───0                                                                                                           │   └───2                                                                                                               │       ├───113                                                                                                         │       ├───114                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │       ├───120                                                                                                         │       └───121`

I'm using pngquant to lower the size of the PNG files that are under `C:\folder\1\0\*.png`. I do *.png because each folder may contain more than 300 small PNG files, but I need to go through all the folders and replicate the exact folder structure at another location with the compressed PNGs.

In Windows I have a shell script that does

```
for d in $(find C:/$folder_name -maxdepth 2 -type d)
do
    path/to/pngquant.exe --ext .png --force 2 $d/*.png
done
```

but this just overwrites all the files in the directory.

This is the help manual of pngquant.

`pngquant, 2.0.0 (March 2013), by Greg Roelofs, Kornel Lesinski.                                                            Compiled with libpng 1.5.14; using libpng 1.5.14.                                                                                                                                                                                            usage:  pngquant [options] [ncolors] [pngfile [pngfile ...]]                                                                                                                                                                                    options:                                                                                                                  --force           overwrite existing output files (synonym: -f)                                                         --nofs            disable Floyd-Steinberg dithering                                                                     --ext new.png     set custom suffix/extension for output filename                                                       --speed N         speed/quality trade-off. 1=slow, 3=default, 11=fast & rough                                           --quality min-max don't save below min, use less colors below max (0-100)                                               --verbose         print status messages (synonym: -v)                                                                   --iebug           increase opacity to work around Internet Explorer 6 bug                                               --transbug        transparent color will be placed at the end of the palette                                                                                                                                                                  Quantizes one or more 32-bit RGBA PNGs to 8-bit (or smaller) RGBA-palette                                               PNGs using Floyd-Steinberg diffusion dithering (unless disabled).                                                       The output filename is the same as the input name except that                                                           it ends in "-fs8.png", "-or8.png" or your custom extension (unless the                                                  input is stdin, in which case the quantized image will go to stdout).                                                   The default behavior if the output file exists is to skip the conversion;                                               use --force to overwrite.`

Comment: How about copying the whole lot and then running `pngquant` *"in-place"* on the copy?

Comment: Yeah, I think this the best solution. I guess the answer was more simple than I thought